# Java class variable has different values in different member functions. How to get the value of variables in specific functions

Tags: java

For Example,

```
class A{
    int a = 0;
    public void a1(){
       a=1;
    }
    public void a1(){
       a=2;
    }
}
```

I want to know what is the value of a in method a1 and a2.

Comment: you can print and check yourself

Comment: Just add System.out.println(a); in your methods, then you'll be able to see what the numbers are equal to

Comment: i don't think this will compile. these are not over overloaded methods. both are a1()

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely give a compilation error. You might want to change that to

```
public void a2(){ ... }
```

instead.

Also you can always use:

```
System.out.println(a);
```

This will print the value of a in the console.

if you are trying to access this from the main method you can always give your functions a return type and use that to display it on the console. It would look something like this

```
public class A{

   int a;

   public A(){
      a=0;
   }
   public int a1(){
      a=1;
      return a;
   }

   public int a2(){
      a=2;
      return a;
   }
}
```

and then have your main method look like this

```
public static void main (String [] args){

   A a = new A();
   System.out.println(a.a1());
   System.out.println(a.a2());

}
```

Comment: Also when you change "int a" in your member function you are not changing the value locally. You are actually changing the value of the variable in the instance of the object A.